# Add item to state after post in API get the id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a component where I can click to "add a study". This click triggers two things :

1 - post in my API

2 - adding to my state to re-render the component.

So, it works BUT when I record the data in my state, I have not the ID of the study and I need it after. So is it possible to do something to have this ID ? Or I am forced to re-call my API to get all my studies ?

My code in my component :

```js
 const addStudy = {
          name : this.newStudy.nameStudy,
          status: "In prepa",
          project: "api/projects/" + this.newStudy.currentIdProject,
          compareStudy: false,
          basic: true
        }

        axios
          .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/studies', addStudy)
          .then(this.$store.commit("addStudie", {projet : this.newStudy.currentIdProject, study :addStudy}))
```

And in my store :

```js
  addStudie(state, {projet, study}) {
    const theProject = state.listProjects.projects.find(p => p.id === projet)
    theProject.studies.push(study)
  }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i seems there is an issue with the request. In my opinion, it should change to

```
     axios
       .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/studies', addStudy)
       .then((result)=>{
               this.$store.commit("addStudie", {projet : this.newStudy.currentIdProject, study :result
        })
    })
```

if you have any problem place let me know

Comment: It's weird, I thought it would work: it seemed like a great idea. It gives me : in my console.log(study) with a status 201. I think he put my request in my Study instead of the datas

Comment: I find the solution so : I add result.data instead of "result" : 


.then((result)=>{
            this.$store.commit("addStudie", {
              projet: this.newStudy.currentIdProject, study: result.data
            })})
So you can edit your message with "data" after result and I check the answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can save your ID in the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) that saves `key` `value` string data on the client side (browser)

```
addStudie(state , id) {
        // do somthing with state then save it into localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('myID', id);
    }
```

And a store getter that returns the id from `localStorage`

```
    theId(state) {
        const savedID = localStorage.getItem("myID")
        return savedID
    }
```

```js
if(theId()){
    // do something with your ID
}
else{
    // ID is not saved in the localStorage yet , call the API
    getDataFromAPI()
}
```